# Problems with docker compose and Dockerfile folder and workdir

Tags: docker, docker-compose, directory, dockerfile

I have the following Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:

  model:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - "mongo"
    command: uvicorn main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
        MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
        MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

    volumes:
      - mongo_db_data:/data/db

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017/

volumes:
  mongo_db_data:
```

and

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN mkdir app_folder

COPY requirements.txt  app_folder

WORKDIR  app_folder

RUN  pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

the problem I saw is that if I build the dockerfile the app runs inside the folder 'app_folder' andit is ok. If I run docker-compose up, if I run the app container interactively I see that
'app_directory > app_directory requirements.txt'. In practice it creates the app_directory folder and inside that another app_directory folder with the app.

Desired behavior (obtained building dockerfile):

app_folder:

- requirements.txt
- app.py

running docker-compose:

app_folder:

- requirements.txt
- app_folder:

  - app.py

The folder in which I run docker-compose up has the structure:

- requirements.txt
- Dockerfile
- docker-compose.yml
- app.py

Thanks for the help